# jQuery onclick play a sound and speed/slow it down

Tags: jquery, audio, performance, onclick, intervals

I want 4 buttons.

1.When you click PLAY a sound plays continously.
For example this sound;  [clicking sound](http://www.wyomingwebdesign.com/files/sound_files/click1.wav)

2.STOP stops the loop.

3.FASTER (interval) increases the bpm

4.SLOWER (interval) decreases the bpm

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I wonder if even modern browsers have good enough timing to keep decent tempo.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't COMPLETELY answer your question/issue, but have you checked out the jQuery plugin 
[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)?

UPDATE:

Looking at your question further, and listening to the sound sample you provided, it looks like you are trying to create a metronome of sorts?  If you're using JS, it's going to be hard to make it very accurate.  Even using setInterval won't guarantee as exact an interval between sounds/clicks as you'd probably want.

Consider something server-side that will actually build a file on-the-fly and stream it to the browser.

Comment: Well yes :) that's in the right direction. I see accuracy would be too difficult to accomplish with jQuery